# Is there a way to get Marketing Insights Grouped by Day of Week in Facebook Marketing API?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to get metrics grouped by Day of Week (Sunday, Monday etc)
I looked for it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns . But couldn't find anything related.

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter to the request: `time_increment=1`

Additionally, you can get weekly data with `time_increment=7` or monthly data with `time_increment=monthly`

If you want the actual day of the week with the response I don't think it's possible. I'd use a library to figure out the day of the week using the date they return.

Answer (score 0):

Day of the week breakdown is not possible yet (I've looked). You'll need to group the data into the day of the week and aggregate the data yourself.